# the name of the image contains symbol "[" and "]"

Tags: android, image, url, special-characters

I was using ijetty to build a server in the mobile phone  and hope that I can share the picture inside  the phone through the URL.
    Here comes the problem:some of the pictures have names contains"["and"]"(eg:http://192.168.20.106:8080/storage/emulated/0/[mmddgg112255].jpg),and if i request this url in WebBrowser,the result is:

HTTP ERROR: 404
    Problem accessing /storage/emulated/0/[mmddgg112255].jpg. Reason:

```
    Not Found


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Powered by Jetty://
```

Then I tried to encode the url like this:
    http://192.168.20.106:8080/storage/emulated/0/%5Bmmddgg112255%5D.jpg
    and this:
    http%3A%2F%2F192.168.20.106%3A8080%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2F%5Bmmddgg112255%5D.jpg.But still not work.The result still not changed.

When I load this picture with universal-image-loader-1.9.3-SNAPSHOT.jar through the url,it give me an error info :

```
  05-17 15:02:19.395: I/System.out(6012): [socket][/192.168.20.122:55155] connected
05-17 15:02:19.395: I/System.out(6012): [CDS]rx timeout:20000
05-17 15:02:19.429: I/System.out(6012): [CDS]rx timeout:100
05-17 15:02:19.430: I/System.out(6012): [CDS]rx timeout:20000
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012): http://192.168.20.106:8080/storage/emulated/0/%5Bmmddgg112255%5D.jpg
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.20.106:8080/storage/emulated/0/%5Bmmddgg112255%5D.jpg
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromNetwork(BaseImageDownloader.java:121)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.download.BaseImageDownloader.getStream(BaseImageDownloader.java:85)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.getImageStream(BaseImageDecoder.java:93)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode.BaseImageDecoder.decode(BaseImageDecoder.java:73)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.decodeImage(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:264)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.tryLoadBitmap(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:237)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.LoadAndDisplayImageTask.run(LoadAndDisplayImageTask.java:135)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-17 15:02:19.434: E/ImageLoader(6012):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

here is my code:

```
package com.example.urldemo;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.naming.Md5FileNameGenerator;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.QueueProcessingType;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private String url1 = "http://192.168.20.106:8080/storage/emulated/0/%5Bmmddgg112255%5D.jpg";
    private String url2 = "http://192.168.20.106:8080/storage/emulated/0/[mmddgg112255].jpg";
    private String url3 = "http%3A%2F%2F192.168.20.106%3A8080%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2F%5Bmmddgg112255%5D.jpg";
    private DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initImageLoader(this);
        initImageOptions();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url2, mImageView);

        // String urlStr =
        // "http://abc.dev.domain.com/0007AC/ads/800x480 15sec h.264.mp4";
        // try {
        // URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        // URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(),
        // url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(),
        // url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        // url = uri.toURL();
        // Log.d("MainActivity", url+"");
        // } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }
    }

    private void initImageOptions() {
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher).cacheInMemory(false)
                .cacheOnDisk(false).considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
    }

    private void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                context);
        config.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
        config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
        config.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator());
        config.diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024); // 50 MiB
        config.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO);
        config.writeDebugLogs(); // Remove for release app
        config.threadPoolSize(5);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Picture's urls like `http://192.168.20.122:8080/storage/sdcard0/mmexport1447409082756.jpg` can be found.
Thank you! I need your help.

Comment: just use `replace` for replacing "[" with nothing ..

Comment: Thank you ,but the name of the picture contains "[]",and I don't want to change the name of the picture.Actually,I thought I can Encode the Url ,but I failed.I don't know why. Thank you，Mr Sergey Glotov.

Comment: use post method for that type of request and dont use url like these.

Comment: Thank you  Pramod mishra ,I forgot about it in the last few days.A few minutes ago,I tried to put the photo in my tomcat server ,but the url which contains "[" works fine.So I think that may be we can solve this problem if we set i-jetty server right.